# Any free books about Bitcoin?

Tags: history

Are there any free (e)books about Bitcoin? There are many articles, blogposts about it all over the internet. But is there actually any comprehensive book about it? Covering not only technical details, but also bitcoin history, social and economic aspects etc. Preferably under Creative Commons or some other free license.

Comment: Traditionally, such "shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange's Q&A format.

Comment: @DavidPerry: Is this question really that bad? We can be pretty sure that only a few books (or no books) exist. A good answer would mention them all. He's not really asking for recommendations, he's asking if any exist at all.

Comment: @DH See: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/whats-up-with-all-the-book-recommendation-flags

Comment: @DavidPerry I read the meta and I think this question is specific enough. He asked for something under the Creative Commons license